# Writing the equivalent of MyRange = Range(ap) for OpenOffice Calc (BASIC)

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

So I have been converting a Code from VBA to OpenOffice Calc (BASIC) and came with an apparently simple problem which I have been dealing with for hours without an answer.

How do I get a Range (Ex: "A2:A4") in OpenOffice BASIC from a Input cell in which exactly "A2:A4" is written?

The code in VBA is very simple

```
ap = Cells(1, 2)
Set MyRange = Range(ap)
```

OBS: The string in ap (Ex:"A2:A4") comes from another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google openoffice Calc basic.  Look at the Openoffice Wiki.  This like show basics on Range ( I cannot put a link address directly yet, so add https://)

wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Cells_and_Ranges

Comment: Thanks mjf55. Actually I solved through 
`CellRange = Sheet.getCellRangeByName(mr)`